# It is possible to deform a plane with some modifier or technique

Tags: cycles-render-engine

It is possible to obtain the same deformation result without having to use the fractal permanently, is there a modifier that allows me to obtain the same result?

[image]

Comment: the Displace modifier, but it will be faster to select random and move up for example

Comment: A noise texture on a displace modifier, or use a texture as displacement on the material nodes.